# Validating a Form With jQuery in Database.. Number Fields Break

Tags: php, jquery, database, validation

I am trying to validate a form which allows user input and I'm using the jQuery plugin found below.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods

The details are being held within a back-end database and validating the date/email/text entries has worked fine and isn't causing any problems.

However, every time I try and specify a number/digits format the back-end php file complains about the data being truncated for 'Age' (One of the database fields) and doesn't execute.

Age is set as an integer in the database, with a max length of 3.. What's causing this to break everytime?

---

My Code -

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#custform").validate({
      rules: {
        DateOfOrder: {
            required: true,
            dateISO: true
        }
        Age: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }
      }
   });
 });
```

My Form Element -

```
  <p>
    <label for="cname">Age</label>
    <input id="Age" name="Age" size="15" class="required" maxlength="3" /><em>*</em>
  </p>
```

Comment: So the back end php is throwing a warning/error saying that Age is being truncated? Or is this a back end validation message that you made? But the jQuery validation plugin isn't outputting any warning/error for the age, correct?

Comment: Post some code, no idea what's going wrong if we can't see what you're trying to do

Comment: @Andrew Jackman Normally when I hit submit on the form it obviously pops up that fields are required etc. However when I have specified the 'Age' must be number/digits and hit submit it bypasses validation and throws the error saying the value for Age is truncated.. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem!  You are missing a comma:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#custform").validate({
  rules: {
    DateOfOrder: {
        required: true,
        dateISO: true
    }, // This comma right here
    Age: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
    }
  }
 });
})
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FTSb5/) is a working jsFiddle for it.

The reason why it still checked for required even though your javascript had the error was because you gave it `class="required"`, which is unnecessary because you are setting it to required in the jQuery ready function (but caused this seemingly strange error).

Comment: Wow it's always the most basic errors, thanks for the fresh pair of eyes!

Comment: @William231 No problem! I have definitely spent hours on problems like these myself :p